# 'Result of initializer is unused error' in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, initializer

What can I do to fix this error?

> Result of '`ForEach<Data, ID, Content>`' initializer is unused

[image]

Comment: Welcome on SO... next time provide your code as code, not as image, link, etc. so someone can copy/paste and fix/modify it.

Answer (score 4):

Your function have to have output in signature, ie

```
func descriptionItem(.. your params here ..) -> some View {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I seemed to have it solved:

```
func descriptionItem(myFrom: Int, myTo: Int) -> some View{
    ForEach(myFrom ..< myTo) { item in
        Button(action: {
            self.theDetail = self.mySites[item]
            self.saveData()
            // self.showAlert = true
        }) {
            Text(self.mySites[item])
                .modifier(ButtonModifier())
        }
        
    }
}
```